# npm run Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

I'm trying to npm run

`HOT=1 node ./node_modules/.bin/react-native-webpack-server start --hot`

getting this error:

```
> projectName@0.0.1 hot /Users/user_name/Documents/dev/app
> HOT=1 node ./node_modules/.bin/react-native-webpack-server start --hot

Segmentation fault: 11
```

there was no such error 12 hours ago. Have no idea why does this happens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The suggestion to delete `node_modules` and re-run `npm install` is a good one. Even better, though: `npm rebuild` will likely fix the problem and be faster (since it won't actually re-download all the files etc.).

Answer (score 4):

There was a major node.js release [yesterday](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v4.0.0/), maybe that's why something went wrong. Best course of action is updating node.js/npm, deleting `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` to install dependencies again.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same issue now in my angularjs webpack project.

I checked the node version and npm

```
node -v

v8.11.3

npm -v

5.6.0
```

I updated the npm to the latest.

```
npm install -g npm@latest

npm -v

6.4.1
```

Now npm install, npm run build is working fine now. :)

Answer (score 2):

rm -r node_modules && npm install

Answer (score 1):

I also got this same error, and was down to a syntax error in one of my SASS files.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue.

**For me it was due to node version mismatch.** I tried running node v8 compatible package, but my node version was set to v6.