# Getting `zsh: segmentation fault npm run dev` error while running dev server for NextJS@13. How to resolve?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, npx

First I ran this:
`npx create-next-app nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn/tree/master/basics/learn-starter"` 
Next I ran this and got the segmentation fault error:

`npm run dev

> dev
> next dev

ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
zsh: segmentation fault  npm run dev`

If I manually change the project to use NextJS@12 and reinstall the node modules, the dev server runs fine.

I am using node@18 and npm@8.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: it's possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479812/npm-run-segmentation-fault-11. delete node_modules then run `npm install` or `yarn install` then run `npm dev`

Comment: Re-installing node_modules did not work. It still gives same error.