# zsh: segmentation fault during npm run dev: NextJs@13.0.4

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, yarnpkg

Working with next and running `npm run dev` or `npm run build` but i keep getting `zsh: segmentation fault  during npm run dev/build`. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479812/npm-run-segmentation-fault-11) step, and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050531/after-upgrading-node-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-error-shows-up-how-can) step. I also [completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) uninstalled and reinstalled node, ran `npm doctor`, and nothing worked. I also reproduced steps above with yarn, but I'm getting `error Command failed with signal "SIGSEGV".` Interestingly previous projects start up on either `npm` or `yarn` except for this latest installation. Could you point me in the right direction, thank you.